# What is a probability model for the event "a random child is a girl"?

Tags: probability

An example in one of my book writes: **A family has two children. You run into one of them and she is a girl. What is the probability that both children are girls given this information. Assuming that you are likely to run into either child, and that which one you run into has nothing to do with gender.**

The way the book solve this problem is this. Let $G_1, G_2, G_3$ be the events that the elder, younger, and random child is a girl, respectively. Then it proceeds to calculate $P(G_1\cap G_2|G_3)$.

I understand the book, but the only thing that really bothers me is the fact that I cannot find a probability model (a sample space, a probability function) to incorporate all $G_1, G_2$ and $G_3$. 
I tried $\Omega=\{GG, GB, BB, BG\}, G_1=\{GG, GB\}$ and $G_2=\{GG, BG\}$. Then there is no way to model the event "the random child$ is a girl with this space.

Then I thought, oh, maybe I make another space to model that event, then form product space. Unfortunately, the result does not come out correct.

How would you do?

Comment: Isn't $G_3=\{ GG,GB,BG \}$, i.e. the model is really "at least one of their children is a girl", and the probability space does not distinguish between which girl you ran into in the GG case?

Comment: If $G_3$ is as you said, then it would not make sense, intuitively. Think about the question: You run into one child of a family that has two children. What is the probability that child is a girl? Intuitively, it would be 1/2.

Comment: Fair point. This is related to the so-called boy-girl paradox which is related to the observation that conditioning on "at least one of their children is a girl" is distinct from "their first child is a girl" even though it seems like the information is the same by interchangeability. In fact really any other independent identifier will turn out to be isomorphic to "their first child is a girl".

Answer (score 3):

The elements of your sample space need to include the information of which child you ran into.  Since you are equally likely to run the older child or the younger child (and this is independent of whether they are boys or girls), you can take your sample space to be $\Omega=\{GGY,GBY,BGY,BBY,GGO,GBO,BGO,BBO\}$, where $Y$ means you ran into the younger child and $O$ means you ran into the older child.  Each of the $8$ elements of $\Omega$ has equal probability.  The events in question are then $G_1=\{GGY,GBY,GGO,GBO\}$, $G_2=\{GGY,BGY,GGO,BGO\}$, and $G_3=\{GGY,GBY,GGO,BGO\}$.

In general, the elements of $\Omega$ need to encode *all* of the unknown (or "randomly determined") data.  Here that data includes not just the genders of each child, but also which child you ran into.

Comment: Thank you very much, Eric. Your answer also helps me understand why my way with product space was wrong. In fact, the way of using product space should give correct answer. I made a mistake in interpreting the evens after the product space was formed.

Comment: @Eric, do you know a convincing intuitive explanation for why $P(G_3)=1/2$ not invoking the sample space?

Comment: @Bananeen: Intuitively, the other child (the one you didn't run into) is equally likely to be a girl or a boy.

Comment: @Eric, I think this explanation is for why the conditional probability is $1/2$, and I am asking about $G_3$ - the event of randomly discovering one of the children is a girl.

Comment: @Bananeen: Oh, right.  Well, intuitively, you have no prior information about the child you meet, so they are equally likely to be a girl or a boy.